# A Level Space invaders project issues

Tags: python, pygame

My enemy sprites are cut in half and one row is lower than the other.

```
pygame.init()

done = False
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

BASE_PATH = abspath(dirname(__file__))
FONT_PATH = BASE_PATH + '/fonts/'
IMAGE_PATH = BASE_PATH + '/sprites/'
SOUND_PATH = BASE_PATH + '/sounds/'
SCORE_PATH = BASE_PATH + '/scores/'





#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

#Classes and Functions

#objects

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

################################################################################
#Enemy class
#Creates class image and positons and size, true or false statments for movement and updating positions
##############################################################################################       
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y,direction,enemy_type):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.EnemyType = enemy_type
        self.Direction = direction

        if enemy_type == 1:
            enemy_image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
            self.Speed = 1
            self.Score = 5

        if enemy_type == 2:
            enemy_image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
            self.Score = 15
            self.Speed = 1

        if enemy_type == 3:
            enemy_image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
            self.Score = 10
            self.Speed = 1

        if enemy_type == 4:
            enemy_image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
            self.Score = 20
            self.Speed = 1

        if enemy_type == 5:
            enemy_image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
            self.Score = 25
            self.Speed = 1

        self.image = pygame.Surface([26, 50])
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image.blit(enemy_image,(0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def move_enemy(self):
        if self.Direction == "right":
            self.rect.x += self.Speed
        if self.Direction == "left":
            self.rect.x -= self.Speed

    #draw image
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


allEnemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
a_enemies = Enemy(200,200,"right",1)
allEnemies.add(a_enemies)'''

#############################################################################################    
#function: in game screen
#draws and calls classes and any functions that will be needed when playing the game
###########################################################################################   
'''def screen_game():
    global lives
    global score
    global gameDisplay


    game_screen = True

#For X coords
    spawnPositions = [90,180,270,360,450,540,630]

    yCoord = 10
#creating enemies
    for n in range(5):
        for i in range(len(spawnPositions)):
            xCoord = spawnPositions[i] 
            enemy_type = random.randint(1,5)
            enemy = Enemy(xCoord, yCoord,"right", enemy_type)
            allEnemies.add(enemy)
        yCoord = yCoord + 50

#creating one player
    player = Player(500,500, 'sprites\\ship.png')

#game loop
    while game_screen:
        #handling events
        eventlist = pygame.event.get()
        for event in eventlist:
                        #print(event)
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                pygame.quit()
                                quit()
                        #handle arrow keys
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                                player.handle_event(event)
                            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                player.handle_event(event)
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                                player.handle_event(event)
                            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                player.handle_event(event)



#draw game display
        gameDisplay.fill(BLACK)

#draw player class        
        player.update()
        player.draw(gameDisplay)

#update enemy positions
        loop = 0


        for enemy in (allEnemies.sprites()):
            if enemy.rect.x < 0:
                enemy.rect.y = enemy.rect.y + 10
                enemy.Direction = "right"
            if enemy.rect.x > 625:
                enemy.rect.y = enemy.rect.y + 10
                enemy.Direction = "left"
            loop =+1

        for enemy in (allEnemies.sprites()):
            enemy.move_enemy()
#draw enemies
        allEnemies.draw(gameDisplay)

#update display
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
```

I've shortened the code down on here to only include what I think are the relevant sections.

How can that be fixed?

Comment: By sprites "cut in half" do you mean that half of the image is drawn?  Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the `Surface` created in the sprite `__init()__` is not large enough to hold the image.

```
    self.image = pygame.Surface([26, 50])    # <-- HERE
    self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    self.image.blit(enemy_image,(0,0))
```

It's not really necessary to load the image, then blit it onto a surface, as the image *is* a surface:

```
    if enemy_type == 5:
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites\\enemy1_1.png")
        self.Score = 25
        self.Speed = 1

    self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
```

Just to simplify this a bit, all the Enemy stats and images could be placed into a list:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__( self, x, y, direction, enemy_type_code ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        enemy_type = [ [ "sprites\\enemy1_1.png",  5,  1 ],  # image, score, speed
                       [ "sprites\\enemy1_1.png", 15,  1 ],
                       [ "sprites\\enemy1_1.png", 10,  1 ],
                       [ "sprites\\enemy1_1.png", 20,  1 ],
                       [ "sprites\\enemy1_1.png", 25,  1 ] ]

        self.EnemyType = enemy_type
        self.Direction = direction
        self.Speed     = enemy_type[enemy_type_code][2]
        self.Score     = enemy_type[enemy_type_code][1]
        self.image     = pygame.image.load( enemy_type[enemy_type_code][0] )
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect      = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x    = x
        self.rect.y    = y
```